# How do I do an IHttpHandler with OwinMiddleware?

Tags: asp.net, owin

I like Owin's lightweight code based configuration registration. Is this the correct way to create an endpoint in Owin?

Right now the below code is broken, It executes (the code in the if-block runs), but I then get a 404.

```
public class HelloOkEndpoint : OwinMiddleware
{
    public HelloOkEndpoint(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }
    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        IOwinRequest request = context.Request;
        IOwinResponse response = context.Response;
        if (request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("hello.ashx"))
        {
            response.Body = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ok!"));
            response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
        return Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I would normally implement this as an ashx

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved it, leaving as a reference since googling ashx, and hander and owin almost entirely deals with middleware and not "endpoint-ware"

```
public class HelloOkEndpoint : OwinMiddleware
{
    public HelloOkEndpoint(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }
    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        IOwinRequest request = context.Request;
        IOwinResponse response = context.Response;
        if (request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("hello.ashx"))
        {
            response.StatusCode = 200;
            //This is the magic, using response.WriteAsync will end the Respose.
            return response.WriteAsync(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Ok!"));
        }
        return Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```